# Parameterized Rmarkdown document on Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want to build a Shiny application where the user can select the input, select output format and click a button to download the report. There are 2 link I think could solve the problem:

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html

This link seems exactly what I want but the sample code is use for RStudio environment, I don't know to publish it as a Shiny app in Shiny Server.

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html

This is the demo from RStudio for Shiny app but I still do not understand how the Shiny app pass parameter to the Rmarkdown document in order to compile the document.

Would someone explain it clearer with an working example.

There was already a question I think is similar to mine here but there was none answer:

[How to link rmarkdown report with shinyapps to export webapp content in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367154/how-to-link-rmarkdown-report-with-shinyapps-to-export-webapp-content-in-r)

Comment: Have you taken a look at this article: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html?

Comment: Yes, the document was not completed as the time I wrote the post (201601)